# Troubleshooting Undefined Variable Logging in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm experiencing an issue with variable logging in my JavaScript code. Despite properly initializing my variables, they appear as "undefined" when I log them. I've reviewed my code multiple times and can't seem to identify the problem. Here's a simplified version of the code that demonstrates the issue:

```
var totalEmission = 0;
totalEmission=Math.trunc(totalEmission);
var flightsTotal = 0;
var carBikeTotal =0;
var publicTransportTotal = 0;
var homeTotal =0;

var emissionCategory =''; 



function calculateEmission(){
    const electricityConsumption = document.getElementById('electricity').value;
    const naturalGasConsumption = document.getElementById('natural-gas').value;
    const coalConsumption = document.getElementById('coal').value;
    const woodenPelletConsumption = document.getElementById('wooden-pellets').value;
    const flightsShorterDistance = document.getElementById('flights-shorter').value;
    const flightsLongerDistance = document.getElementById('flights-longer').value;
    const carDistance = document.getElementById('car').value;
    const motorbikeDistance = document.getElementById('motorbike').value;
    const busDistance = document.getElementById('bus').value;
    const tramDistance = document.getElementById('tram').value;
    const taxiDistance = document.getElementById('taxi').value;
    const subwayDistance = document.getElementById('subway').value;
    const trainDistance = document.getElementById('train').value;

    // Perform the calculations
    const electricityEmission = electricityConsumption * 0.44;
    const naturalGasEmission = naturalGasConsumption * 0.054;
    const coalEmission = coalConsumption * 1.0;
    const woodenPelletEmission = woodenPelletConsumption * 0.06;
    const flightsShorterEmission = flightsShorterDistance * 0.20;
    const flightsLongerEmission = flightsLongerDistance * 0.33;
    const carEmission = carDistance * 0.24 * 0.07;
    const motorbikeEmission = motorbikeDistance * 0.24 * 0.05;
    const busEmission = busDistance * 0.31 * 0.6;
    const tramEmission = tramDistance * 0.023;
    const taxiEmission = taxiDistance * 0.187;
    const subwayEmission = subwayDistance * 0.040;
    const trainEmission = trainDistance * 0.041;

    // Calculate the total carbon emission
    totalEmission = electricityEmission + naturalGasEmission + coalEmission + woodenPelletEmission +
                        flightsShorterEmission + flightsLongerEmission + carEmission + motorbikeEmission +
                        busEmission + tramEmission + taxiEmission + subwayEmission + trainEmission;
    totalEmission=Math.trunc(totalEmission);
    flightsTotal = flightsLongerEmission + flightsShorterEmission;
    flightsTotal=Math.trunc(flightsTotal)
    carBikeTotal = carEmission+motorbikeEmission;
    carBikeTotal=Math.trunc(carBikeTotal)
    publicTransportTotal = taxiEmission+trainEmission+tramEmission+subwayEmission+busEmission;
    publicTransportTotal=Math.trunc(publicTransportTotal)
    homeTotal = electricityEmission+naturalGasEmission+coalEmission+woodenPelletEmission;
    homeTotal=Math.trunc(homeTotal);

    
    if (totalEmission < 2000) {
      emissionCategory = 'Good';
    } else if (totalEmission >= 2000 && totalEmission <= 5000) {
      emissionCategory = 'Fair';
    } else {
      emissionCategory = 'Bad';
    }

}

document.getElementById('calculate-btn').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculateEmission();
    
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams({
      carBikeTotal: carBikeTotal,
      totalEmission: totalEmission,
      flightsTotal: flightsTotal,
      publicTransportTotal: publicTransportTotal,
      homeTotal: homeTotal,
      emissionCategory: emissionCategory
    });
  
    // Redirect to the results.html page with the calculated data in the URL
    window.location.href = 'results.html?' + urlParams.toString();
    console.log(carBikeTotal);
    console.log(totalEmission);
    console.log(flightsTotal);
    console.log(publicTransportTotal);
    console.log(homeTotal);
    console.log(emissionCategory);
  });
  

export { carBikeTotal,totalEmission, flightsTotal, publicTransportTotal, homeTotal,emissionCategory };
```

I've checked for typos, scoping issues, and made sure that the variables are assigned values before logging them. However, the output consistently shows "undefined". I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Logging *after* updating `window.location.href` might be a problem.

Comment: Not sure what you think `export { carBikeTotal,totalEmission, flightsTotal, publicTransportTotal, homeTotal,emissionCategory };` is doing.

Comment: unsure how you are getting undefined. What exactly is showing that?

Comment: Try logging your `URLSearchParam` object; is it constructed as expected? Does your URL after navigation look as expected? Try to [minimize your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as much as possible, and share it with us!